# unwatch any watcher when another watcher is running

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

```
watch: {
options: {
      handler () {
        this.get_re_list() 
            .then(data => {
                this.re = data.result
                this.totalM = data.count
            })
      },
      deep: true,
    },
'$route.params.homeCode':  {
  handler () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          reApi.getRe({page:'', count:'', home:this.$route.params.homeCode}) 
            .then(re => {
                this.re = re.result
                this.totalRe = re.count
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return reject(error)
            })
      })
  },
  deep: true,
  immediate: true
}
},
```

I have route path as `path: '/:homeCode?',` `homeCode` is optional so I have kept `?` at the end.
**Problem:**  When I pass the `homeCode` the `'$route.params.homeCode'` is called but immediately the next route i.e `options` is executed. How do I stop executing `options` watchers when `'$route.params.homeCode'` is running?

Edit1:

I have options for external pagination:

```
options: {
          page: 1,
          itemsPerPage: 40,
        },
```

Comment: Do you need `options` in a watcher,  can it not be run on `mount` or  `created`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need `options` in a watcher,  can it not be run on `mount` or  `created`?
In addition the `watch` function does return an `unwatch` although then you would need to setup the watcher again. see here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch.
A possibly simpler solution would be to just set a variable to `true` inside your . `route` watch and check it in the options watch.
Like so:

```
watch: {
options: {
      handler () {
        if (this.routeCalled) return
        this.get_re_list() 
            .then(data => {
                this.re = data.result
                this.totalM = data.count
            })
      },
      deep: true,
    },
'$route.params.homeCode':  {
  handler () {
    this.routeCalled = true
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          reApi.getRe({page:'', count:'', home:this.$route.params.homeCode}) 
            .then(re => {
                this.re = re.result
                this.totalRe = re.count
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return reject(error)
            })
      })
  },
  deep: true,
  immediate: true
}
},
```